# Laravel Eloquent - Find average for a group of days in a month

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

i have 2 colums. One is datetime (imeromina_metrisis) and the other has integers (apotelesma). What i am trying to do is to get the average integer number for each day so that i can send it to a chart. Do you have any idea how can i do this?

This is my table [here](http://postimg.org/image/kjxzwpk2p)

Comment: Does the `xronos_metrisis` column have any bearing on your results, or should it be ignored for the purposes of these averages? It appears to be a grouping column.

Comment: Ηι, i dont want `xronos_metrisis`. I only need the average `apotelesma` for each day.

Answer (score 2):

We need to get DATE format first instead of using DATETIME since you need data for each day. Try this query

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
        ->select(DB::raw('avg(apotelesma) as count, DATE(imeromina_metrisis) day'))
        ->groupBy('day')
        ->get();
```

refer how to select raw expression [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this.

```
$avg = Model::where('imeromina_metreisis', $carbon)->avg('apotelesma');
```

See:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates

Just be aware of your date column. `$carbon` is a variable representing the Carbon date and time object that Laravel uses extensively. If the average is for an entire day, but you're using datetime (which includes hours/minutes/seconds), you will want to do something like this.

```
$carbon = Carbon::now()->startOfDate();
$avg = Model::where('imeromina_metreisis', '>=', $carbon)
    ->where('imeromina_metreisis', '<=', $carbon->copy()->endOfDay())
    ->avg('apotelesma');
```

And yes, those are built-in Carbon methods. It really is a great library.

Edit: More documentation on Carbon. I think you want arbitrary day ranges.
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I imagine that the question isn't just asking for the way to get the average value for `apotelesma` for a given `imerominia_metrisis` but instead to get grouped (by date only, ignoring time) results to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution, by using Eloquent + Fluent, to be able to use my relationships. **This is my code to get a collection of all my Articles + User + Rating average** :

```
$articles = Articles::where('state', '=', '1')
->with('user')
->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
->select(array('articles.*',
    DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average')
    ))
->groupBy('id')
->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')
->get();
```